# Find all lines that follow a pattern and begin with a character

Tags: grep, search

So I have many Jekyll posts in `_posts` with metadata YAML in the header, including `categories`, like this:

```
---
excerpt: "I am an excerpt"
categories:
- tips
- programming
- howto
- another-tag
layout: blog
title: I am a Page Title
created: 1267026549
permalink: blog/27-05-2017/clean-url-goes-here
---
```

So I know how to grep for the `categories` line and show `n` lines after (`-An`)... but is there a way to make it show all the following lines that begin with `-` as, obviously, each post has a different number. Maybe all lines until `layout`?

Comment: will `layout` always be a stop point for all matched lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended tool for text processing is `awk`.

Try this:

`awk '/categories/,/layout/ { if (!/layout/) print }' your_file`

This command prints everything starting from `categories` until `layout` without this line itself.

Output:

```
categories:
- tips
- programming
- howto
- another-tag
```

If you only want to have the items between `categories` and `layout` you could simply add a second pattern to the `if` condition like this:

`awk '/categories/,/layout/ { if (!/layout/ && !/categories/) print }' your_file`

Then your output will look like this:

```
- tips
- programming
- howto
- another-tag
```

Comment: Brilliant, Thanks, @john-goofy - perfect.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use `pcregrep` (Perl-compatible regular expressions):

```
pcregrep -M 'categories.*(\n-.*)*' file
```

or using lookahead assertion:

```
pcregrep -M 'categories(.|\n)*(?=layout)' file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -e '/^categories:/,/^[^-]/!d;//d' yourfile
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it with awk. When you find the header line, print it, and keep getting the next line and printing it, as long as the next line starts with a `-`.

```
awk '$0=="categories:" { do { print; getline } while (/^-/) }'
```